# Add item in ArrayListAdapter from another activity Using SharedPreferences

Tags: android, android-listview, sharedpreferences, android-adapter

I want to add some elements from `MainActivity` to another `activity`, where I have an `arrayList` but my problem is that, When I insert something the deal is done, but is added only 1 element. I want to add multiple elements to the `arrayList`. In `MainActivity` i have 2 `EditText` and 2 `buttons`(Save and `GoToNextActivity` where i put an intent for a transition from the `MainActivity` to the list.class) What can i do to adding more elements to the list when i press the save button?

```
public class items {

private String username;
private String password;

items(String user,String parola){
    username=user;
    password=parola;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
}


public class itemsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<items> {

private static final String LOG_TAG = itemsAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

public itemsAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<items> item) {
    super(context, 0,item);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    View listItemView = convertView;
    if (listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_items, parent, false);
    }

    items curentItems=getItem(position);

    TextView user=(TextView)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.list_user);
    TextView password=(TextView)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.list_password);

    user.setText(curentItems.getUsername());
    password.setText(curentItems.getPassword());


    return listItemView;
}
}
```

public class list extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences= getSharedPreferences("user", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String name=sharedPreferences.getString("username","");
    String password=sharedPreferences.getString("password","");

    final ArrayList<items> login = new ArrayList<items>();
    login.add(new items(name,password));

    itemsAdapter itemsAdapter=new itemsAdapter(this,login);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_activity_container);
    listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

}
}
```

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
EditText username;
EditText password;
TextView show;
Button save;
Button display;
Button go;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    username=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    show=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.show);
    save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
    display=(Button)findViewById(R.id.displayInfo);
    go=(Button)findViewById(R.id.goToList);

    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences= getSharedPreferences("user", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();

            editor.putString("username",username.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("password",password.getText().toString());
            editor.apply();

          //  Toast.makeText(this,"Saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    display.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences= getSharedPreferences("user", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String name=sharedPreferences.getString("username","");
            String password=sharedPreferences.getString("password","");
            show.setText(name+"  "+password);
        }
    });

    go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,list.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Shared Preferences` save a *key-value pair*. To save multiple elements in `SharedPreferences` you need to assign a unique key for each element. Let's name our key as "userID".

```
int userID = 0;
```

> and save user details to shared preferences like this

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences= getSharedPreferences("user", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();

        editor.putString("username_"+userID,username.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("password_"+userID,password.getText().toString());
        editor.apply();
```

When you add another user object, increment userID

```
++userID;
```

So now your `shared preferences` will contain two elements having keys `<username_0>` and `<username_1>`.

Also while getting data from `preferences`, don't forget to use correct key.

```
String name=sharedPreferences.getString("username_"+userID,"");
```

For loops : Suppose you have 5 elements and you want to add them to your `List`

> in `onCreate` of `MainActivity`.

```
 final ArrayList<items> login = new ArrayList<items>(itemCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        // command below will be executed 5 times, and i will range from 0 to 4(both inclusive)
        login.add(new items("name" + i, "password" + i));
    }
    // now our login list has 5 elements(namely name0,name1...name4)
```

> In click listener of save button, save entire `list` to `shared preferences`

```
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("user", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                // save entire list using loop.
                editor.putString("username" + i, login.get(i).getUsername());
                editor.putString("password" + i, login.get(i).getPassword());
            }
            editor.apply();

            //  Toast.makeText(this,"Saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

> in `List activity` , read data from preferences.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

    final ArrayList<items> login = new ArrayList<items>();

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("user", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        String name = sharedPreferences.getString("username" + i, "");
        String password = sharedPreferences.getString("password" + i, "");

        login.add(new items(name, password));
    }

    itemsAdapter itemsAdapter = new itemsAdapter(this, login);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_activity_container);
    listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

}
```

However in `ListActivity` you don't need to read data from `shared preferences`, you can bundle data in the `Intent` used to start `ListActivity`, and in `ListActivity` get data from Intent.

Comment: I did, but now it's saved only first value I enter, my list don t increment

Comment: you are adding only a single element to the list, to add multiple values at once use a loop.

Comment: ok, but i dont' know how to implement that loop in this situation, you can show me , please ?

Comment: Do you know how can I take the length of login list to use it in loop? I try with login.size() but this don t work

Comment: where it didn't worked, you may log list size, if using `login.size()` before adding elements to list, it will return 0.

Comment: for(int i=0;i<login.size();i++) this didn't work and int l=login.size(); -> for(int i=0;i<l;i++) don t work

Comment: have you added elements to `login list` before accessing its size?

Comment: yes, the list have elements, when i put a int in loop, they are all showed, but when i put login.size() i have a white screen